# Nexus artifact not displaying in yum

Tags: nexus, yum

I have a nexus repository that was working like a dream for the past 2 years, last week I made a boo boo and deleted the repository, I went through the steps of recovering and it seems to be working fine.  I now cannot see all artifacts in the repo in yum (a new artifact).

On a server I have a connection to my yum repo, in /etc/yum.repos.d/ like so.  This did not change.

```
[releases]
name=Release
baseurl=http://{my nexus}/nexus/content/repositories/releases
enabled=1
protect=0
gpgcheck=0
metadata_expire=30s
autorefresh=1
type=rpm-md
```

When I try to look for my package it is not there.

```
yum list available | grep myPackage
```

When I run the command below I cannot see the new package but can see other packages. and I can install the other packages.  So permissions or connection to the repo isn't the issue.

```
yum list available | grep release
```

When I look at the nexus repository, the meta-data.xml, file structure, everything looks the same. from one package to the other.

Any ideas how to get it to update? or a setting in nexus that needs to be changed.

Comment: Have you cleaned `yum cache`, rebuilt the `repodata` after adding your package into the repo ?

Comment: Oh yeah, I've gone as far as remove the repo connection from the machine and putting it back.  cleaning cache and making it along the way.

Comment: I would love to know how you resolved this. I have the same problem

Comment: The cache clearing resolved for me. Thanks @iamauser